# Hyper-V Switch separate WIFI NIC Kali Linux

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, kali-linux, network-adapter, hyper-v-manager

Situation:
I have a Hyper-V external switch connected to my Wi-Fi network adapter. I have also opted to NOT allow network adapter sharing in the switch manager for the Wi-Fi network adapter, since I want it separated from my host traffic.

On my host I am connected to the internet with my Ethernet NIC.

When I look at my network adapters, I notice Hyper-V has created a network bridge with my wifi NIC and Hyper-V Switch. (Probably because of disabling network adapter sharing)

Problem:
Now the problem is when I open my Kali VM I have only Ethernet Network as an option. No wifi connection is show and adding one is not possible... Obviously I have no network connection as well.

Preferably I would love to be able to have both ethernet AND wifi NIC within my kali VM, but I don't think that is possible since no 2 switches can be assigned to a VM.

If that is not possible, the next best thing would be that my kali VM uses my wifi NIC, with separated from my host.

I don't understand why this does not work... I thought Hyper-V is a layer 1 Hypervisor so theoretically, should it not be possible?
I have been searching for 2 days and tried a lot of different options... What are my limitations? Is it even possible to do what I want?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Preferably I would love to be able to have both ethernet AND wifi NIC
> within my kali VM, but I don't think that is possible since no 2
> switches can be assigned to a VM.

To have two active NICs in Kali or like workstation machine, you need one of them to be connected via USB.

You would be better off with VMware Workstation or possibly Virtual Box which all have USB pass through and will allow you to connect a USB Wireless Card (I use Panda Wireless for Kali).

Hyper-V does not easily allow USB pass through. You need a Generation 2 machine and then enable Enhanced Session Mode.

I do have a Kali machine in Hyper-v but I find it much, much easier with VMware.

[USB pass through Hyper-V](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/performing-hyper-v-usb-passthrough/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I prefer a layer 1 hypervisor (hyper-v is free for me). If all else keeps failing I might resort to another hypervisor and go from there

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot do USB pass through with what you have. Virtual Machines (all that I know) are better with a USB card for the additional wireless connection.  I do have Hyper-V on another machine